# What are the words for rank up or down?

Tags: word-request

I want to say to people to **rank** up or down my work.
What words should I use?

Answer (score 3):

The verb you are looking for is probably

> [***rate***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rate#Verb_2) : (transitive) To evaluate or estimate the value of.     "They *rate* his talents highly."

So, for example, you might ask someone:

> Please rate my work on a scale of 1 to 10.

Comment: Can I say "rate up" or "rate down"?

Comment: I would not say "rate up" or "rate down".  I might, however, decide to use a ranking system in which rank is determined based on number of votes received.  And then you could say, "please *vote up* or *vote down*".

Comment: So vote up/down is about rate?

Comment: @user80042- vote up and vote down is about voting. You could choose to establish a rating scale with criteria and then use voting to determine a particular thing's position on that scale, i.e., its rating.  Comparing that thing's position with the position of other similarly rated things would determine its ranking.  Just note that you can use voting for other things that rating, and you rate things by other means than voting.

Answer (score 2):

I think the words you were looking for are **promote** and **demote**.

Here are the definitions as per [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/):

[Promote](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/promote) 
  and [Demote](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/demote)

Comment: Welcome to ELL! I think this answer is great (I'm upvoting it), but it would be better to provide supporting definitions and/or examples that demonstrate usage of these words.

Answer (score 1):

The word I would use is **grade.**

A person or thing can be up- or down- graded.